# I was unable to understand why am i getting undefned?

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why I am getting undefined.
Is it something about the event loop?
I have tried the following code:

```
var v = { s: '92', t: '212', h: '33' }
var c=['s','t']
for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    var key=c[x]
    console.log(v.key) 
}
```

Result:

> undefined

Why this is undefined ?
I have also tried this:

```
var v = { s: '92', t: '212', h: '33' }
var c=['s','t']
for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    var key=c[x]
    console.log(v.[key])  
}
```

I need to access the v object with the `key` variable, not the `key` property.

Comment: You are looking for "key" not the variable key. Use bracket notation like you did with the array. `v[key]`

Comment: Thank you very much @epascarello